# how to pass a value from a gridview to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, dialog

Hi this is my row in gridview in ASP.Net

```
<ItemTemplate>
<a id="aOpen" onclick="javascript:Open(<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)['DocTypeCode'] %>)" >A_<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Id"] %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Open(var id) {
        var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/View.aspx?id="+id) %>';
        OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(strPageURL, 750, 500, "View Document Type");
        return true;
}
</script>
```

I would like to pass the Id value from the gridview to the javascript and open a new page with query string.
How should I try ?
Mine does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want simply:

```
<%# Eval("DocTypeCode") %>


onclick='javascript:Open(<%# Eval("DocTypeCode") %>)" >A_<%# Eval("Id") %></a>
```

Also note that this

```
<a id="aOpen"
```

is a huge problem, since all dom elements must have **unique ids**

Comment: @kevin - you mean how should you assign unique ids to your anchors?  Unless you actually need to reference these anchors in a script by id somewhere, I would say just leave off the id altogether

Comment: How about 

<input type="button" value="<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DocTypeCode"] %>" onclick="javascript:Open()" /> 
?

Comment: I don't know how to pass the value to the javascript and put the value as a query string.

Comment: @kevin - you can just add the values you need to your querystring using Eval like in my answer above

Comment: I got **Too many characters in character literal** Error. I am not good at Javascript. : /

Comment: @kevin - just start slow.  See if you can get the content output just as plain text in your ItemTemplate. then slowly add in the other stuff around it -- like your anchors with querystrings and such.

Comment: @Kevin - woot!  Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this below code:

```
onclick="javascript:Open('<%#Eval("DocTypeCode") %>')"
```

is a syntax problem, I should add the character ''

Comment: I tried like this <img src="~/Imgs/GroupJoin.png" id="imgJoin" alt="Invite" runat="server"                     onclick="javascript:PostRequest('<%#Eval("ID") %>')"  /> but i am getting a syntax error. its inside a gridview item template